# File upload and delete if the order is not completed

Tags: php

I am thinking about solving the problem of uploading files by store visitors. Let's imagine a simple store. On the product page, the customer sees an additional "File Upload" field. The uploaded file will be added to the order.

The customer uploads the file when adding the product to the cart.
Then I have two scenarios - A: The customer makes a purchase, B: The customer abandons the cart and never returns to the store. But what to do with uploaded files?

I wonder what the best approach would be for scenario B?

1. Upload the file to the /guest_files directory (accessible only for admin)
2. If the customer places an order, move the file to another directory, eg "order/1234/client_files"
3. Run CRON job once a day at night - clean the /guest_file directory

or

1. Upload the file to the /client_files directory
2. If the session has expired, delete the files uploaded by the user
   But, Is it possible to call an event in PHP when the session ends?

or

I know that during the upload, files go to the temporary directory and then are deleted, unless move_uploaded_file is called. Is it possible to extend the time of a file's presence in the temporary directory?

or

All sessions are stored in /tmp directory. For example current session has id: 0pnkm91lcgjtikftoe1imedt07 and the session file is /tmp/sess_0pnkm91lcgjtikftoe1imedt07
I upload files to the: /tmp/uploads/0pnkm91lcgjtikftoe1imedt07/ directory. CRON job run every 5-15 mins (algorithm below):

> 1. GET all sess_* file names from /tmp
> 2. FOR every directory in /tmp/uploads ($dir_name) check if '/tmp/sess_'.$dir_name exists
> 3. IF sess_ does not exist THEN delete /tmp/uploads/{sessionid} directory

Thanks for any reply

Comment: You don't need a cron job, just delete any expired files as part of the main process.

Comment: Another my thought... Will I have a denial of service because of disk space? I need to store files for 24h (in scenario B). I use CSRF protection. User can upload 1 file, 50MB max size.

Comment: Many roads lead to Rome... Another option would be to store the data with order-cart info in the database and remove that after x hours/days. Personally i would go for the cronjob, but that's not per se the best (depending on framework use etc). For file storage, I would not do that on the server itself. but use e.g. AWS S3, Azure Blob or BlackBlaze B2 (cheapest). This means the server disk can have a small size, and will never get full. I would defenitly use a throttle on the upload...

Comment: I am testing right now solution for store files in IndexedDB and then upload on checkout. I think it will be good for me

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've tried several options. I think that IndexedDB is the right answer.
Here, I prepared simple lib to handle a files queue and store to the IDB.

[filequeue.js repo](https://github.com/piatkowski/filequeue.js)